# Optional Parenthesis in Regex

Tags: python, regex

Using the following string in python

```
1 - GENERAL 1

    1.1 RELATED DOCUMENTS   1

    1.2 SUMMARY 1

    1.3 DEFINITIONS 1

    1.4 INFORMATIONAL SUBMITTALS    2

    1.5 GENERAL COORDINATION PROCEDURES 2

    1.6 COORDINATION DRAWINGS   3

    1.7 REQUESTS FOR INFORMATION (RFIs) 4

    1.8 PROJECT MEETINGS    6
```

I'm trying to create a regit expression to put the section, title, and page number in 3 groups. So far I have

```
 (\d)(\.|\d|\s|-)+\s+([^a-z]+?)\s+\d
```

which can handle all situation except the (RFIs). How can I grab this too? 
Note: Sometimes the strings may contain subsection in lowercase that I do not want. This is why [^a-z] is present. Additionally, RFIs may not always be text in parenthesis.

Update:

```
END OF SECTION



    Project No. 151219.00   012500 - 1 of 3 Substitution Procedures

            Rev. 0, 07/23/15

            Issued for Construction
```

Comment: Show some examples of other strings that make it complicated (subsections, RFIs), etc.).

Comment: looks like a simpler "number, followed by anything, followed by a number" is all you really need.

Comment: `^\s*[1-9\.]*\s*[A-Z^a-z\(\)\-\s]+[A-Z^a-z\(\)\-]\s*[0-9]*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly three parts contained in your string.

> First is section which is mainly composed of digits followed by decimal and digits
>
> Second is anything upto page number. This mainly starts from word
>
> Third is page number in the last which is *usually* digits

Your regex contains too many alternations which are not required.
So you can use this regex

```
^\s*(\b\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)\W+(.*?)\s*(\b\d+\b)$
    <---------------->   <--->   <------->
        Section         Content  Page Number
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY3hZ1/4)**

If subsection can contain values like `1.1.1` etc., you can use

```
^\s*(\b\d+(?:[.]\d+)*)\W+(.*?)\s*(\b\d+\b)$
```

*Regex Breakdown*

> `\b` is [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
>
> `\W` is equivalent to `[^\w]` which in turn is `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` (Mind the `^` which signifies match anything except those in character class)

```
 ^ #start of string
 \s* #Match any spaces in starting
 (
  \b #word boundary
  \d+ #Match digits
  (?:[.]\d+)* #Non-capturing group to match . followed by digits any 
              #number of times(due to *). It matches after . like .1.1 etc
 ) 
  \W+ #Match any non word character
  (.*?) #Match anything upto page number given in next
  \s* #Match spaces if there
  (\b\d+\b) #Match page numbers in last(due to $).
 $ #End of string
```

Comment: why is it better? A little explanation will make this answer much better.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! However, I'm new to regex. Just started learning this morning and this confuses me, \b\d+(?:[.]\d+)*)\W+ . Would you mind explaining what is happening here? Thanks

Comment: I have one more question for you rock321987. One of the documents I was parsing contains the string I posted under update and the expression you provided picks up this unwanted piece of information. How can I edit the expression you provided to ignore these? Thanks

Comment: @Jstuff i dno't think its picking anything..can you check **[here](https://regex101.com/r/kY3hZ1/5)**

Comment: I most be implementing something wrong. When I do text = (re.search(r'^\s*(\b\d+(?:[.]\d+)*)\W+(.*?)\s*(\b\d+\b)$', input_strong, re.M) it does not return any matches. When I do text = (re.findall(r'\s*(\b\d+(?:[.]\d+)*)\W+(.*?)\s*(\b\d+\b)', input_string) it finds the matches in the text box I posted plus the ones in the second text box which are the ones I do not want. Why does the first method not return any matches?

Comment: Never mind I just used p = re.compile(r'^\s*(\b\d+(?:[.]\d+)*)\W+(.*?)\s*(\b\d+\b)$', re.MULTILINE) and the re.findall. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend something like this

```
    ^\s*([\d.]+)[\s-]*\s+(.+?)\s+(\d+)$
```

Since you said you are in python, this affords you some more abilities when it comes to things like comments. For example:

```
    ^\s*(?#Section)([\d.]+)[\s-]*\s+(?#Title)(.+?)\s+(?#Page)(\d+)$
```

Regex is super powerful, but usually unreadable if you are new to it or just out of practice. Comments are a Godsend in these cases!

A full implementation would look like this:

```
    re.search(r'^\s*(?#Section)([\d.]+)[\s-]*\s+(?#Title)(.+?)\s+(?#Page)(\d+)$', input_string, re.M)
```

where re.M indicates it should run in MULTILINE mode, making ^ match the beginning of each line rather than the beginning of the whole input. Same for $ and end of line/input

Comment: Is it better to use re.search with the re.M flag and ^,& or re.findall and omit the flag and ^,& ?

Comment: I suppose that approach could work as well, though this one will return groups with 3 matches. The larger dataset you pass into each match, the more chance a hard to track down edgecase will end up shifting your data by one spot or something